# How to create plist file inside eclipse in android?

Tags: android, plist

I am new to Android application, i want to create one plist file inside resource folder, i tried to create plist file, i have spent 2 hours, but i cannot create this, please help me.

Thanks

I tried:

Create New folder as "raw" from resource, then to create xml file inside raw, but the error comes.

Comment: I have recently added the plist file in cocos2d-android and it works for me ...
https://github.com/wangtz/HeartBreaker , Download the zip file and checked it ... how he used thr plist file in the android

Answer (score 1):

Android does not use plist files, they are a feature of iOS/MacOS/OsX.

Comment: You would be better off creating a standard xml or json file. I am assuming that you want to use a plist because it is also being used by an iOS app, but your iOS app should be able to consume xml or json just as well as a plist.

Comment: thanks, but i have one doubt, have one xml file inside countryname, then where i insert the xml file in android app, because parse that xml file

Answer (score 0):

Android project architecture does not use plist, you have AndroidManifest.xml to customise your App, or if you want a resource just create a file on yourProject/res and use it

Answer (score -1):

I use the following sample... from source: http://solutionforandroid.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/how-to-parse-plist-in-android-and-how.html

```
public class ProductsPlistParsing {   
Context context;

   // constructor for  to get the context object from where you are using this plist parsing
    public ProductsPlistParsing(Context ctx) {

        context = ctx;
    }

    public List<HashMap<String, String>> getProductsPlistValues() {

       // specifying the  your plist file.And Xml ResourceParser is an event type parser for more details Read android source
        XmlResourceParser parser = context.getResources()
                .getXml(R.xml.products);


          // flag points to find key and value tags .
        boolean keytag = false;
        boolean valuetag = false;
        String keyStaring = null;
        String stringvalue = null;


        HashMap<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        List<HashMap<String, String>> listResult = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        int event;
        try {
            event = parser.getEventType();

             // repeting the loop at the end of the doccument 

                 while (event != parser.END_DOCUMENT) {

               switch (event) {
                       //use switch case than the if ,else statements  
                case 0:
                        // start doccumnt nothing to do
                       // System.out.println("\n" + parser.START_DOCUMENT
                       // + "strat doccument");
                      // System.out.println(parser.getName());
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // end doccument
                    // System.out
                    // .println("\n" + parser.END_DOCUMENT + "end doccument");
                    // System.out.println(parser.getName());
                    break;
                case 2:

                    if (parser.getName().equals("key")) {
                        keytag = true;
                        valuetag = false;
                    }
                    if (parser.getName().equals("string")) {
                        valuetag = true;
                    }

                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (parser.getName().equals("dict")) {
                        System.out.println("end tag");
                        listResult.add(hashmap);
                        System.out.println(listResult.size() + "size");
                        hashmap = null;
                        hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if (keytag) {
                        if (valuetag == false) {
                            // hashmap.put("value", parser.getText());
                            // System.out.println(parser.getText());
                            // starttag = false;
                            keyStaring = parser.getText();
                        }
                    }
                    if (valuetag && keytag) {
                        stringvalue = parser.getText();

                        hashmap.put(keyStaring, stringvalue);
                        // System.out.println(keyStaring);
                        // System.out.println(stringvalue);
                        valuetag = false;
                        keytag = false;
                        // System.out.println("this is hash map"
                        // + hashmap.get(keyStaring));
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplication(), keyStaring,
                        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                event = parser.next();
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 //here you get the plistValues.
        return listResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should at least summarize what the blog says (and link to the original source of course), links don't last forever and your answer is useless if the link dies.